# What is the $\delta$ in fluctuation model

Tags: ideal-gas

I found this formula :
$G-G_0=\frac{-nkT}2\delta^2$ on this [Site](http://fc.retecivica.milano.it/~paolo.ripamonti/resources/Fluctuations.html) and I'd like to ask what does the $\delta$ stand for?

Comment: Read the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next line right beneath the equation you copied says:

...where $\delta=\frac{V-V_0}{V_0}$ is the condensation (e.g. relative volume variation).

Is it too difficult to read one more sentence?

Comment: And can you tell me what does it stands for in Czech ? My problem was that when I translate it then it gives no sense for me...

Comment: Dear user, I don't quite follow whether your question is serious. AFAIK none of the physics terminology or notation is derived from Czech. The Greek letter $\delta$ which is the Greek counterpart of "d" is used for a big fraction of quantities that look like a *difference* because the word difference starts with a "d" and "differentia" means "difference" in Latin, see http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=difference - Well, the more accurate story is that delta actually comes from Greek word διαφορά, diaphorá - also "difference".

Comment: I haven't said that it is derived from Czech, I asked because I'm from Czech rep...